# React highcharts unable to call function from data label onclick

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I need to call a react function on datalabel on click. I'm void of answers.
I'm using highcharts

```
 chart: {
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'y'
            },

 dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return `<div><span class="text-center">${this.point.y}</span>` +
                            '<button onClick={this.openModal} class="btn-primary graph-custom-hover">i</button></div>'
                    },
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: "none",
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        wordWrap: 'break-word',
                        width: '125px',
                        lineHeight: '10px'
                    }
                }
```

I have a openModal function like

```
  openModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            modal2: !this.state.modal2
        });
    }
```

When I use this  my rendering goes like

```
<button onclick="{this.openModal}" class="btn-primary graph-custom-hover">i</button>
```

in the actual html.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to seems that you don't trigger the function callback on the click event. Instead of `onClick={this.openModal}` it should be `onClick={this.openModal()}`.

Check this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-k30l0

---

EDIT:

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-29u2u

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still on your demo, I'm seeing 
```
ReferenceError
openModal is not defined
HTMLButtonElement.onclick
https://k30l0.csb.app/:1:2
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
This error overlay is powered by `react-error-overlay` used in `create-react-app`.

Comment: @Aswath my mistake, try this approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-29u2u

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work with my code
with an error
Uncaught TypeError: this.updateClaimsPerStage is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (****:1)



    updateClaimsPerStage() {
        alert(this);
    }

this.updateClaimsPerStage = this.updateClaimsPerStage.bind(this);

 '<button onClick={updateClaimsPerStage()} class="btn-primary graph-custom-hover">i</button></div>'

I'm not using options from inside the state

Comment: @Aswath I am afraid that this error doesn't say anything to me. Please try to reproduce it on the online editor which I could work on.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `onClick={this.openModal}` is the right way to set `onClick` because you set the function that should be called. You DON'T call the function directly.